# Get values from numpy 2d array by using a list of tuples as indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of tuples: `[(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)]`
And I have my 2d numpy array:

```
array([[8, 6, 5, 9, 3],
       [7, 9, 7, 9, 1],
       [2, 1, 8, 8, 6],
       [7, 1, 5, 1, 3],
       [6, 7, 1, 1, 5]])
```

How can I get the values from the 2d array located by using the positions from the list with numpy?
I should get the diagonal: `[8,9,8,1,5]`

Comment: Is this always a diagonal, or is this just an example?

Comment: You need to convert the list to a tuple of lists, one for each dimension `([0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transpose the list of tuples, and pass these as items in a tuple:

```
>>> b = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
>>> a[tuple(np.transpose(b))]
array([8, 9, 8, 1, 5])
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> req_index = [(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)] # this is your tuple index list
>>> arr = np.array([[8, 6, 5, 9, 3],
       [7, 9, 7, 9, 1],
       [2, 1, 8, 8, 6],
       [7, 1, 5, 1, 3],
       [6, 7, 1, 1, 5]])
>>>
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> [arr[i][j] for i, j in req_index]
[8, 9, 8, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

```
 a=np.array([[8, 6, 5, 9, 3],
   [7, 9, 7, 9, 1],
   [2, 1, 8, 8, 6],
   [7, 1, 5, 1, 3],
   [6, 7, 1, 1, 5]])

np.diag(a)
```

prints `array([8, 9, 8, 1, 5])`.